# Struggling to parse response from API service

Tags: json, parsing, graphql

Struggling to parse what appears to be a simple response from an API service (GraphQL / JSON). The response is retrieved as `String` based on `HTTP request`, and have tried different approaches (using both `JsonObject/JsonParse` and `JsonArray`from `com.google.gson`library to get desired string elements to String, although without being able to extract anything.

Anyone willing to share suggestions how to parse and get `"total"` and `"startsAt"` from the response shown below?

```
{
"data": {
    "viewer": {
        "homes": [
            {
                "currentSubscription": {
                    "priceInfo": {
                        "current": {
                            "total": 0.5626,
                            "energy": 0.4336,
                            "tax": 0.129,
                            "startsAt": "2019-11-14T20:00:00+01:00"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: did you check the following answer? @Stian Kjøglum

Answer (score 0):

You can get the json value like this

Assign the response to some variable like res.

For ex :

```
var res = {
         "data": {
            "viewer": {
               "homes": [
                  {
                     "currentSubscription": {
                         "priceInfo": {
                             "current": {
                               "total": 0.5626,
                               "energy": 0.4336,
                               "tax": 0.129,
                               "startsAt": "2019-11-14T20:00:00+01:00"
                             }
                          }
                      }
                  }
                ]
           }
       }

 var total=res.data.viewer.homes[0].currentSubscription.priceInfo.current.total;

 var startAt = res.data.viewer.homes[0].currentSubscription.priceInfo.current.startsAt;

 console.log('total is: ',total);
 console.log('startsAt: ', startsAt)
```

Comment: Appreciate your proposal. Although, the proposed solution using ...res.data.viewer... does not work for me, as 'data' becomes highlighted as an uninitialized variable.

Solution for me was to use getAsJsonObject from nested tree:

JsonObject newObject = (JsonObject) Object.getAsJsonObject("data").getAsJsonObject("viewer")
      .getAsJsonArray("homes").get(0);

Comment: Anyway you got your solution, keep it up :)